# Grafana dashboard link with quick ranges

Tags: sql, time, dashboard, grafana

I'm building a dashboard in Grafana. One of my graphs is based on this query:

```
SELECT
  users.name as Name,
  users.last_name as Last,
  users.email as Mail,
  sum(orders.total_amount) as Sales
FROM orders
INNER JOIN users ON orders.user_id=users.id
WHERE orders.status=4
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

So I'm looking for the top clients based on how much they spent. What I need now is that the total sales change with the Time Ranges of the dashboard. Right now I have the same result with every Quick Range I use (it returns me the total sales in all the database and not in the time range I request). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check used Grafana datasource doc (MySQL, PostgreSQL). There are available macros, which you will use in your SQL `WHERE` time condition.

- http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/postgres/#macros
- http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/mysql/#macros